# "A black man" in Follow God video clip?

Tags: music-video, rap

In [Kanye West - Follow God](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivCY3Ec4iaU), the clip ends with this dialogue:

> My dad came to visit me at one of our ranches in Cody, Wyoming. He talked about his love for fishing, and how he could come here in the summers. It took me 42 years to realize that my dad was my best friend.
>
> He asked me, 'How many acres is this?' I told him 4,000. He replied with these three words:
>
> **A black man?**

What does he mean?

Comment: @PiedPiper well the site's description was "Music Fans", so I was expecting it to be adequate for posting here. If not, then please suggest me another site to post this interesting, IMHO, question. :)

Comment: Maybe this would be a better fit on English Language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rhetorical question. The father is saying in effect "A black man makes it far enough to own a 4000 acre ranch? I'm proud of you".

Comment: Ehm, typical Kanye West then...

Comment: This is probably correct, but I'd also mention that the black people freed from slavery at the end of the Civil War were each promised 40 acres of land as reparations from the government, a promise never fulfilled when the order was reversed by the notoriously racist and regressive president, Andrew Johnson. https://www.npr.org/sections/codeswitch/2015/01/12/376781165/the-story-behind-40-acres-and-a-mule